# Excel Web Part Scroll Bar Defaults to middle of page

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel-web-access-webpart, excel-access-web-part

I placed an Excel Web Part on one of my pages.  Whenever it loads, the bottom scroll bar (the one that goes left and right) is not at the far left side (where the default usually is), but it's in the middle, requiring that the user scroll left to see the entire worksheet section.

When I pulled up the Excel file that the web part feeds from, it comes up on the left side.

- Has anyone else run into this situation?
- Is there something I can do about this?

Comment: Hi @DanJ Could you please share a screenshot for your current page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the issue is caused by the excel will record the last used cell when saving the file. When opening the file again, it will automatically redirect to that cell. So that, it will automatically navigate to the middle of the excel file when opening it using Excel web part because the last used cell is in the middle.

You can follow the steps below to reproduce that:

1. Create a excel file and enter some data in it.
2. Click in a cell, for example, cell R5, and then save the file.
3. Upload the file to a SharePoint library.
4. Open the file from the library, you will find it will automatically active cell R5 and it will be scrolled to the R5 to make it available in the screen.
5. Render this file using the Excel web part, the same situation. It will automatically active cell R5 and it will be scrolled to the R5 to make it available in the screen.
6. Edit the file and click in the cell D5, then save the file. The last used cell is changed to D5. When opening the file again, the cell D5 will be active.

You can locate the cell at the beginning of the worksheet section when saving. Upload this file and use this file in Excel web part, the issue should be resolved.

Comment: Strangely enough, this worked.  I edited A2, saved it, and voila! Of course, I went and used a named range after this, so scrolling wasn't an issue anymore.  But this did the trick - and should have been obvious, but you know how that goes.  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but I've never edited a cell in the area where it persists in loading the scroll bar to see.  I only edit the top left of my sheet and whenever I load the page, it always scrolls at least one page to the right and one page down, to an area I never edit.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/123009)